# How to stack transparent items in Dreamweaver CS6

Tags: transparency, dreamweaver, transparent, outline

**ULTIMATE GOAL: Make a formed transparency where images can show through but are shaped by the form itself. The images are rollover buttons and turn from grayscale to color with hover**

So the picture below (link) shows what I want to happen in Dreamweaver CS6. I used PS to create this image. I simply took the "person portion" and deleted it so the picture turned out as a white box with a transparent inside. My plan was to simply plant this image into DW and then place the rest of the color images beneath it by placement of the IMG tag.

I figured it would turn out like what you see below but it has not. I simply get a full white page (tested offline, not uploaded to the server). If I add a picture, there is no hint that the PNG with the transparency is even existent.

So now, what would be your suggestions? Would it be easier to just use FW and make slices of the work as seen below? In that case I would just have to match all the pieces of the body up like Tetris when working in DW. It just seems there is a MUCH easier way of doing this and somehow I am making it extremely hard.

Please ask if you need further information. Thank you so much.

http://i1195.photobucket.com/albums/aa400/SteffaneTimm/MeFirstSuccess_zps146c6716.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You could save the outline as a .PNG with alpha transparency as you have. To get the seperate images with the rollover effect you could try something like the below. (not using any canvas trickery). Create an image thats double the height of the strip you want, put the black and white version in the top half, and the colour version of the same image in the bottom half.

If you are having difficulty seeing the white outline you could try setting the page background to black temporarily.

To double check you have linked to your image files correctly you could also try pressing f12 in chrome and looking at the Resources tab in Frames > Images.

```
.container {
width: 500px; height: 800px;
}

.image-strip {
height: 200px; width: 500px; float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}

.image-strip img:hover {
margin-top: -200px;
}

.woman-outline {
position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;
height: 800px; width: 500px;
background: url('woman.png') no-repeat;
z-index: 1000;
}


<div id="container">

   <div class="image-strip"><img src="1.jpg" /></div>
   <div class="image-strip"><img src="2.jpg" /></div>
   <div class="image-strip"><img src="3.jpg" /></div>
   <div class="image-strip"><img src="4.jpg" /></div>

   <div id="woman-outline"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the assistance. I did get everything to work and actually did a hover-fade effect. Now my issue is that when beneath the transparency--the image can be seen but is not clickable and the hover effect does not work. If I pull it outside of the transparency--it works. So I know it isn't an issue with the effect in itself. Any reasons why the image can be seen but not clicked while under the transparency? Here is the link-->http://webdesign.miad.edu/stimm/testsite/